# How can I treat dates as if there were no DST adjustment?

Tags: ios, timezone, dst

Edit: My solution is below.

I have a sort of calendar-related app where the user is able to jump backward and forward certain integer numbers of days. In testing the app around midnight, I realized there is a DST-related problem, and I'm looking for the best solution.

The app is not really based on any calendar in iOS. However, I display the Gregorian date and time so the user has a reference to a familiar date and time.

One of the built in jumps in time is 73 days, which is about 1/5 year. Common dates used will be March equinox +/- integer multiples of 73 days. The problem comes, for example, when jumping from March equinox to a date 73 days previous, because the March equinox is likely to be in DST, whereas the other is not. It depends on the timezone setting on the system. The app, however, has nothing to do with timezone, so I'd rather display times as if there were no such thing as DST, yet still using the local timezone. I hope that makes sense.

Any suggestions on how to achieve this? If the question is too vague, maybe I can add more detail, but I don't want to confuse things by adding too much.

EDIT: I've decide to link sample screen prints from the app to illustrate what's going on. This picture:
http://victorspictures.com/trollart/h37a90c77#h56122c20
shows the configuration for this year's equinox. The caption explains how to read the device. Follow to the next two pictures in the gallery to see how to use the device to calculate the date of Easter.

Anyway, swipe gestures allow the user to move +/- one day or +/- 73 days, which is where the problem arises. I'm adding time to the date display, and maybe that is really all I need to do.

Solution: Celeda's suggestion

Added this method:

```
- (NSDate *)setNoon: (NSDate *)date
{
   NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
   NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:NSYearCalendarUnit|NSMonthCalendarUnit|NSDayCalendarUnit fromDate:date];
   [components setHour:12];
   NSDate *todayNoon = [calendar dateFromComponents:components];
   return todayNoon;
}
```

Then, everywhere a jump was made, it was simply encapsulated in the new method:

```
newDate = [self setNoon:[previousCode]];
```

Comment: Would it help if you did your date ± jumps around noon instead of midnight (and then just convert back to midnight for database storage/display at the end of the process if required)? It's a hack, but it might get rid of your problem more easily than the "true" solution.

Comment: I thought of that, and I started working out how to do it in my head. The epoch for my app is spring solstice 1975, which is 3 minutes before midnight local time, and I thought at first the few minutes before midnight was the problem, so I switched the epoch to midnight, which just shifted the problem over one hour. I found that out because I was doing the same sort of testing for about an hour, heheh. I'm thinking maybe I should do something like getting the local timezone, checking if DST is in effect, then setting the timezone as an offset from GMT rather than using a timezone name.

Comment: I'm not an iOS programmers, so I can't speak for that, but in general, you will have problems like this any time you try to use integers instead of dates.  Good implementations of date/time libraries take DST and Timezones into account.  A "day" is not always 24 hours, it could be 23, 24, 25 or even some fraction inbetween - depending on the DST rules in effect.

Comment: @Matt, I am using date objects, not integers. For the device in question a "day" isn't always 24 hours because the device does not reckon hours at all. The basic unit of the device is a day. Day change happens at local midnight in the app.

Comment: Without DST your calculations are going to be wrong and the date you are showing to the user is going to be incorrect. A certain date +/- a certain number of days should include DST, otherwise the calculation is wrong and you "missed" a day.

Comment: That's working off a flawed assumption, Victor.  For example, in Brazil, when they transition to DST in the spring, they go from 23:59:59 to 1:00:00.  There is no midnight on that day.  I suppose I should know more about your particulars before I get too critical though.

Comment: Yes. Local midnight is a blurry concept that really is more fantasy than anything. The troll operates the device by waking up at midnight (it's the troll's midnight), manipulating the device and going back to sleep. The app calculations are all integer calculations relative to an epoch, except for the reference display. I think my solution will be to add time to the display.

Comment: @Celada, if you will post your comment as an answer, I will accept it. Since time is not particularly relevant for the jumps, I think I will set the app to change to local noon before the jump, then apply the jump. After a minute of inactivity, it reverts back to current date/time where it will simply display the time with correct local timezone.

Answer (score 0):

It appears, based on your comment to Hot Licks's answer, that you have some number `d` representing days since the 1975 vernal equinox (which was at 1975-03-21 05:57:00 UTC), and you want figure out the corresponding day on the Gregorian calendar.

We can use the `NSDate`, `NSCalendar`, and `NSDateComponents` classes to perform this computation.  To avoid the effects of DST, we need to set the time zones of the calendar and formatter to UTC.

```
NSInteger d = 73 * 189; // days since the 1975 vernal equinox

NSTimeZone *utcTimeZone = [NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"UTC"];

NSCalendar *calendar = [[NSCalendar alloc] initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
calendar.timeZone = utcTimeZone;
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init]; 
formatter.dateFormat = @"yyyy-MM-dd";
formatter.timeZone = utcTimeZone;

NSDateComponents *epochComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
epochComponents.year = 1975;
epochComponents.month = 3;
epochComponents.day = 21;
epochComponents.hour = 5;
epochComponents.minute = 57;
epochComponents.timeZone = utcTimeZone;
NSDate *epochDate = [calendar dateFromComponents:epochComponents];
NSLog(@"epochDate=%@", epochDate);
NSLog(@"epochDate from formatter=%@", [formatter stringFromDate:epochDate]);

NSDateComponents *offsetComponents = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
offsetComponents.day = d;

NSDate *computedDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:offsetComponents toDate:epochDate options:0];
NSLog(@"computedDate=%@", computedDate);
NSLog(@"computedDate from formatter=%@", [formatter stringFromDate:computedDate]);
```

Try commenting out the lines that set the time zone to UTC on the calendar and/or the formatter to see how DST changes the results.

For more information, read the [*Date and Time Programming Guide*](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#Documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DatesAndTimes/DatesAndTimes.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000039i).

Comment: The date jumps are not being done in the Gregorian calendar, so using NSDate methods is not relevant. In any case, my question was meant to be a simple one: Can I somehow use a fictitious timezone that is like the local timezone but with no DST? I think I've decided not to go that route, but I'd still like to know the answer.

Comment: UTC has no DST.  Why use a fictitious time zone when you can use a real one?

Comment: Also, you haven't given any information about how you are representing dates or making your computations.  So it was reasonable to assume that you are using the standard objects provided by the SDK.  If that's not the case, you need to explain how you are representing your dates and computing with them.

Comment: I said, "The app is not really based on any calendar in iOS." The NSDate class assumes a calendar. The calendar I'm using is not one of the ones available, because I invented it. See my original posting, which I have edited with a link to a screen print from the app. You can also read how the app works at victorengel.com/trollcalendar if you like. It needs updating for the new version of the app, though.

Comment: I have revised my answer based on your comment on Hot Licks's answer.

Comment: That's still not a good answer because you are doing your calculations in the Gregorian calendar. This is not a Gregorian calendar. The Gregorian calendar is used only to get the epoch from Gregorian components and for the reference display. My solution is to switch to local noon when doing any jumps.